# Javascript is losing variable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lots of pages structured like this:

```
<body>
    <table><tr><td align="center" width="100%">
    --PAGE HTML--
    </td></tr></table>
</body>
```

And I have to change those the page to the following structure for a short period of time:

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; min-height: 960px; text-align: center;">
    --PAGE HTML--
    </div>
</body>
```

So I decided to use jQuery.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var PageHtml = $("td:first").html();
    $("table:first").remove();
    console.log(PageHtml);
    $("body").html('<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 960px; text-align: center;">'+PageHtml+'</div>');
});
```

The problem is that instead of having the expected result I have

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; min-height: 960px; text-align: center;"></div>
</body>
```

(I don't have the page html in the div element)

Now for diagnostic purposes I added the line `console.log(PageHtml);` And it does return the correct HTML string.

I'm out of ideas to make this work, any suggestions?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/3xpk8/). How exactly do you include your code in the page?

Comment: Are you using tables for layout?

Comment: You don't have the option to update the source? Inline CSS is only a moderate improvement over tables.

Comment: @Bergi Well it an old website, and the only place I can put some code that would go in all pages is in the footer since the footer is included in all pages. And The javascript code showed is in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @NickDugger Yes website was design very poorly and now have to find some wierd and uncool solution,.

Comment: @Mathletics No I can't change source since it would take days for only a few hours of that page html structure :/

Comment: Can you link the website? Btw, you really should change the source (as you have access to it) instead of doing some client-side scripting. There are powerful transformation tools if the number of files is huge.

Comment: Javascript is doing no such thing

Comment: @Bergi For now I am unsure if I can link the source, I will re-comment you with a source if I can.  Also, I was so stuck with the idea of jquery that I never thinked of notepad++ with a simple find&replace,.  Great idea!

Comment: @GeorgeJempty It should not I know,. But for some reason it is.  Perhaps it is beacause of the very big number of lines of html

Comment: Can you put the line `console.log` after the `$("body").html(`

Comment: When you open up the browsers dev tools are you seeing any Javascript errors?

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 No, Normaly when I would have an undercleared it would pop me an error. but there console is clean.  It like there would be at some point a `PageHtml = ''` but the only place where the var get setted is with the function return of `$("td:first").html();`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var $div = $("<div />").css({
    'width': '100%',
    'min-height': '960px',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'color': 'red'
});
$div.appendTo('body');
$div.html($("td:first").html());
$("td:first").remove();
```

Comment: Hum It is still doing the same :/